# How can I avoid creating a function within this loop?

Tags: javascript, jshint

```js
function createMarkers(locations, infowindow) {
  // create an array of markers from Model data
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    // Get the position from the location array.
    var position = locations[i].location;
    var title = locations[i].title;
    // Create a marker per location
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: position,
      title: title,
      address: locations[i].address,
      city: locations[i].city,
      url: locations[i].url,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    // Push the marker.
    markers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, infowindow) {
      return function () {
        getVenueDetails(marker.position, marker.city, marker.title, function (windowContent) {
          infowindow.setContent(windowContent);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      };
    })(marker, infowindow));

    bounds.extend(position);

  }
  // Extend the boundaries of the map for each marker
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

I am working on my personal project and on the code below I am getting an error message W083 Don't make a function with in a loop any ideas on how to fix this error? file: 
message: 'Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. (W083)'
at: '99,53'
source: 'jshint'
code: 'W083'

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. You can ignore it if your code works properly and you know the potentially unexpected side effects of creating a function in a loop like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the function in the loop, i.e. using the `function` keyword is a loop, create a variable as a reference to the function, `markerClickListener` in my example, and pass it to `addListener`.

```
function createMarkers(locations, infowindow) {

    // Create the listener function
    var markerClickListener = function(marker, infowindow) {
        return function() {
            getVenueDetails(marker.position, marker.city, marker.title, function(windowContent) {
                infowindow.setContent(windowContent);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        };
    };


    // create an array of markers from Model data
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        // Get the position from the location array.
        var position = locations[i].location;
        var title = locations[i].title;
        // Create a marker per location
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: position,
            title: title,
            address: locations[i].address,
            city: locations[i].city,
            url: locations[i].url,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });

        // Push the marker.
        markers.push(marker);

        //Pass The function declared above
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', markerClickListener(marker, infowindow));

        bounds.extend(position);

    }
    // Extend the boundaries of the map for each marker
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```